# How can I see a namespace?

Tags: xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

So if I know an XML-namespace, e.g. xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture"

How can I "see" this namespace?

For example if I write into my web browser: http://www.w3schools.com/furniture, it doesn't find any webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often considered good practice to put some kind of description of a namespace at the location identified by the namespace URI, but it's not mandatory and many people don't bother. That's especially likely to be the case for a namespace like this one, which was probably just invented for an example or tutorial and was never designed for real information interchange. In general there's no guaranteed way of finding information about the namespace: it might not even be documented. The answer is the same as if you want to find information about anything: search on Google.